# How do I correctly configure my homestead.yaml file?

Tags: laravel, installation, homestead

I am setting up Laravel for the first time.
Now I have the following information in my homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: C:/Users/MyName/Documents/web/sites
  to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:
- map: consulting.app
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/consulting

databases:
- homestead
```

where Homestead is installed at C:\Users\MyName\Documents\web\Homestead and I have a folder called "sites" at the same level, containing a "consulting" folder with a index.php in it.

However, when I call http://consulting.app in my browser, the page cannot be found. Same, when I append :8000 at the end of the url.
I also configured the hosts file to

## 192.168.10.10       consulting.app

and after that ran vagrant provision

I really can't help myself anymore an I am glad for any help. Thanks!

EDIT:
Now that I've changed my

```
- map: C:/Users/MyName/Documents/web/sites
```

to

```
- map: ~/Documents/web/sites
```

I can access my page via localhost:8000, but that way only..

Comment: What happens when you change  `/home/vagrant/sites/consulting` to `/home/vagrant/sites/consulting/public`?

Comment: It doesn't change, unfortunately..However (before changing my code to your suggestion), I realized that I can access my page via localhost:8000, but still not via consulting.app.
Also in my folder "consulting" is currently only an index.php, which is successfully echoing "Test", once I open localhost:8000

Comment: Also, check my EDIT in the original post to see how I got a part-archievement I can't understand either

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem is on a deeper level, as I can open the site by typing the IP manually, but not via consulting.app .
Therefore, this question is no longer relevant. If you have similar issue, check out, whether you can access the IP adress. If not, find out, why your /etc/hosts file doesn't resolve the hostname to the IP.